# Minecraft 1.11.2 replace slot

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a map here. Does anyone know how to use replace slot a command block with a name of the command block and a command inside it? I would really appreciate it. I tried this:

```
/replaceitem entity @a slot.hotbar.0 minecraft:command_block 1 0 {display:{Name:"test",BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/say",}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to reformat your NBT info:

```
/replaceitem entity @a slot.hotbar.0 minecraft:command_block 1 0 {display:{Name:"test"},BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/say"}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could be an error in Bracket placing and Types of brackets. May also need Quotation marks around `Command` but I truly don't know exactly. Hope I helped!